# Facing Difficulty in importing DropWizard Microservice Project to intellij

Tags: intellij-idea, dropwizard, microservices

I am unable to import Dropwizard Microservice Project to intellij , after import the project structure is not the expected one .It is adding up source main folders as main1 , main2 ..etc to the project structure.

Project structure After import

```
   root
      sub1
      main1
      main2
      main3....
```

This is the actual project structure

```
root
    REST
       mavenModule1
                 sub1
                    pom.xml
                 sub2
                    pom.xml
                 pom.xml
       mavenModule2
                 sub1
                    pom.xml
                 sub2
                    pom.xml
                 pom.xml
    UI
```

Comment: Could you provide the github url if any , so that we can try to import it .also it would be better if you add the snapshots of the idea , while you importing the project to know.

Comment: Also don't you have a parent pom.xml of your project, normally if its a multi-module project , import using the parent pom.xml works perfectly fine.

Comment: There is no parent pom as all the modules are independent

Comment: @AmitK i really cannot give any hint on that since it is confidential.

Comment: Normally you can import project in Intellij by selecting the pom.xml, let me know if this works for you, if not let me know how you are importing it .

Comment: @Amit it is a microservice project and each module is like an independent project under a common folder or sub folders.

Comment: Ok . I think i cannot open projects in intellij as directories ,there should be a relation . Based on my research i found it is nearly not possible or it will not make sense if i try to import multiple projects in the same workspace

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136778/discussion-between-amitk-and-user3247425).

Comment: try following http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42453969/how-to-import-existing-maven-spring-mvc-tomcat-project-on-intellij-idea/42454048?noredirect=1#comment72054293_42454048 and let me know if it works.

Comment: did it work , please comment , so that others can be benefited.

Comment: No it did'nt ,now i am opening each micro services separately and coding.