# How to import existing Maven + Spring MVC + Tomcat project on Intellij IDEA?

Tags: java, maven, spring-mvc, tomcat, intellij-idea

I'm new to IntelliJ IDEA. I've imported project from git repository. Now I try to run it on Tomcat 8.5 with no success. I understand that I need to configure maven command to package my project in war file, but I do not know where to do it.

Comment: So, what is your question exactly? What the title says, or what the text says? If that's what the title says, choose File - Open..., then select the pom.xml file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Import your project in Intellij.**

Go to file->new->project from existing source-> then select the `pom.xml` from your project location on your disk. then follow the instruction given by IntelliJ.Check the box for maven to automatically download dependency for your project.

**Create war from your code**

Run `mvn clean package` from the directory where `pom.xml` is present. it will create `war` file in the `target folder` of same folder, where `pom.xml` is present.

**Create war file from idea**

Click on the right most icon of `maven project` in idea and there you will see different maven lifecycle, click on `package` to create war file of your project. again same war file will be available inside the target folder of your project.

follow below images for more clarity:-

[image: create war file from intellij]

[image: target folder inside which war is present]

Comment: This way it would be not possible to use hot deployment/updates while developing. Using exploded artifact produced by IntelliJ IDEA is recommended.

Comment: @CrazyCoder does it possible with the community edition of Intellij IDEA ?

Comment: @CrazyCoder nevermind , i got your answer on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17229674/adding-tomcat-server-in-intellij , so my solution is the only way if you are on community edition of IDEA.